# Coral Dev Board Not Recongized on mdt shell

Tags: linux, ubuntu, usb, mdt

I have tried to follow the steps on google's getting started for their Coral Dev Board (https://coral.withgoogle.com/docs/dev-board/get-started/). However when I reach the step where you switch from the mircoB USB cable to the USB-C cable the following line does not create the desired outcome (open the board's shell prompt) when entered on the host computer (Ubuntu 16.04)

```
mdt shell

Waiting for a device...
Unable to find any devices on your local network segment
```

Any suggestions to get this to work? I haven't found much help online.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know if this would help, please take a look at this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58499659/coral-dev-board-mdt-devices-cant-find-any-devices/58502230#58502230

Answer (score 2):

I had the similar problem. Here is my suggestion:

Remove all connections, just plug micro-B USB cable, then run:

`screen /dev/cu.SLAB_USBtoUART 115200`

If it shows blank, wait a couple seconds, then plug usb-c **power** cable, the system of the dev board will start loading, the login prompt will come out(If you have flashed the image already). Log in, and plug the usb-c cable into **data port** (** and keep the micro-B USB cable in at the same time**), then run the commands on **your host laptop terminal**:

`mdt devices` or `mdt shell`

This solution works for me only when I have turned on the wifi of the dev board and connect it to the same wifi network. If you want to turn on the wifi network of coral dev board, run the command on `screen` terminal:

`nmtui`

The Network Manager TUI prompt will come out then you can connect to your wifi network.

Hope this would help!

Answer (score 0):

I am a month too late and my issue was on Mac. I will give my solution here so that it helps others.

By default, 'Mendel' is not added to networks and hence the error. To fix this, go to Network under System Preferences --> Click on the '+' icon --> Choose mendel from the interface dropdown.

execute the `mdt devices` command and you should be able to see your dev board.

Answer (score 0):

Flash your `iptables` before

```
sudo iptables -F
mdt devices
```

Comment: Welcome to Super User! While this may answer the question, it would be a better answer if you could provide some explanation **why** it does so.